# InvalidArgument=Value of '2' is not valid for 'index'. When trying to type characters individually

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, sendkeys

I'm trying to type a string with small spaces between each character.

Then I use this I'm getting an error: `InvalidArgument=Value of '2' is not valid for 'index'.` in line: `if (currentChar == lbMessage.Items[tickCount].ToString().Length)` I did similar with text box but I can't do it for ListBox.

```
private void Space(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tickCount < lbMessage.Items.Count)
    {
        SendKeys.Send(lbMessage.Items[tickCount].ToString().Substring(currentChar++, 0));
        tickCount++;

        if (currentChar == lbMessage.Items[tickCount].ToString().Length)
        {
            tmrSpace.Enabled = false;
            SendKeys.Send("{enter}");
        }

        if (tickCount >= lbMessage.Items.Count) tickCount = 0;
    }

    tmrSpace.Interval = random.Next(50, 100);
}
```

This works for a textbox field:

```
private void Space(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendKeys.Send(txtText.Text.Substring(b++, 1));

    tmrSpace.Interval = random.Next(50, 150);

    if (b == txtText.TextLength)
    {
        tmrSpace.Enabled = false;
        SendKeys.Send("{enter}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this:

```
if (tickCount < lbMessage.Items.Count)
{
    SendKeys.Send(lbMessage.Items[tickCount] // etc, irrelevant
    tickCount++;

    if (currentChar == lbMessage.Items[tickCount].ToString().Length)
```

Now suppose that `tickCount` is exactly `lbMessage.Items.Count - 1`. The *first* time you index into it that's fine - but then you increment `tickCount` and index *again*, at which point `tickCount` will equal `lbMessage.Items.Count`, and you'll get that exception.

Your code isn't particularly clear to me (I'm tired) but you may well want to move the increment of `tickCount` to later in the code...

Comment: Well my increments fork well from my older code which include text box and when I do typing with out spacing between characters. I'm my code I'm reading line by line and then trying to type the line with spaces between characters. Perhaps the I have problem with .Length property. Can I use this to check how man characters does the string have?

Comment: @NewHelpNeeder: It's not really clear what you mean, but I've explained why you're getting the exception - your `if` condition only ensures that it's valid to evaluate `lbMessage.Items[tickCount]` *before* `tickCount` is incremented. Do you understand that part?

Comment: Ok, I think I get this now. You were right the placement of my incrementing variable was wrong. Thanks.